# Best technology to have a specific person's proximity in a room turn on a light outside the room

Tags: bluetooth, proximity-sensor, bluetooth-low-energy

I need help deciding which technology to use so that, when a specific person (1 out of 6) walks into a room, their specific ID is recognized and the corresponding colored light is illuminated outside of the room.

The building in which this will take place is still under construction and therefore the system can be hardwired in.

Originally I had wanted to use RFID but it seemed a bit pricey. I then considered Bluetooth but I am just not as tech savvy as I would have to be to use that.

**What technology could I use to recognize the device on the person and activate the appropriate light?** The amount of data used in the recognition step doesn't seem to be a problem, as we just need to differentiate between 6 distinct identities. But I'm just no fully aware of what is available out there.

Comment: Unless the walls, floors and ceilings incorporate RF shielding, any RF-based system isn't going to be able to distinguish between being inside the room or being just outside it.

Comment: What is allowed to 'put on' each person? passive (no battery) electronics? powered electronics (with battery)? How long must it last? Can the 'tag' be required to be at a certain place/orientation (cap, shoe, forward looking, etc)? Can it be large? (e.g. differently colored hats, 4 x 4 " scannable tag on the chest)?

Answer (score 3):

Since it seems allowable for the person to wear some kind of tag (you mention RFID), I'd probably start by looking into IR.  Tags would wake up every few seconds and send a short message via IR.  These would be on/off modulations of something like a 40 kHz carrier.  That allows use of sensitive and cheap IR receivers, like the Vishay TSOP series for example.

Keep the messages short, but with enough of a checksum so that random noise or message collisions are very unlikely to look like real data.

Each tag is transmitting for such a short time that collisions are unlikely.  Even when they do occur, clock drift between tags will make collisions of successive messages unlikely.  This is a good reason NOT to use a crystal.  This is a easy job for even a tiny microcontroller.  I've done more complicated things with a PIC 10F202.  The PIC can clock out the 40 kHz carrier pulses directly.

Comment: So what would be the range of the receiver? do the tags require a power source? Would it be able to recognize two different signatures and turn on two separate lights for one room?

Comment: They will need to be powered.  This is just like a little remote control that only sends out a single signal.  The receiver will be able to differentiate the signals so long as each transmitter is sending a different IR signal.

Comment: @user: Range is usually anywhere within a normal room, although it's a problem if tags get covered up with cloth or flipped around so that they are pointing at your body instead of outwards.  Of course sending IR requires power.  A 2032 coin cell should last months though, if done right.  Each tag sends out a different ID, which is how different people are detected.